# How to disable/enable a button based on the certain condition of a text box?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" id="txtID" maxlength="16" />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="button" value="Search" id="btnSearch" disabled="disabled"/>
</td>
```

The button `#btnSearch` is disabled/enabled by following conditions on `#txtID`

1. The minimum length is 6
2. Allow digits, copy/paste
3. If both (1) and (2) are satisfied, and enter is pressed, the `#btnSearch` should be clicked

I have these three jQuery functions:

```
$("#txtID").bind("propertychange keyup input paste", function () {
    var mid = $.trim(this.value);
    if (mid.length < 6) {
        $("#btnSearch").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else {
        $("#btnSearch").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});

myself._findjcontrol("txtID").keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.keycode == 13) {
        myself._findjcontrol("btnSearch").click();
        return false;
    }
});

$("#txtID").keydown(function (e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13]) !== -1 ||
    (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
    (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
        return;
    }
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

How do I combine the above three functions into one?

Answer (score 0):

Since your first `bind` function is listening to multiple events, you can move the other two function inside of it with some small modifications:

1. Change `keyup` to `keypress` (which is preferred, anyhow)
2. Consistently refer to `e` instead of `event` throughout function

```
$("#txtID").bind("propertychange keypress input paste", function (e) {
    var mid = $.trim(this.value);

    if (mid.length < 6) {
        $("#btnSearch").attr("disabled", true);
    }else {
        $("#btnSearch").removeAttr("disabled");
    }

    if (e.keycode == 13) {
        myself._findjcontrol("btnSearch").click();
        return false;
    }

    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13]) !== -1 || (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
        return;
    }

    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```